# Как редактировать хедер и футер

Tags: php, opencart

Подскажите, как редактировать номера телефонов в хедере и футере [на этом сайте](https://tumba-umba.com.ua/).
Я так понимаю, что модуль не установлен, а только вручную. Точнее, в каком именно файле можно добавить номер телефона.
И ещё добавить ссылки на соцсети в футере.

Comment: это opencart 3. читайте как там что устроено. Или нанимайте специально обученных людей за деньги.

Comment: Сайт на версии 2.3.0.2

Comment: В настройках нужных полей нет, в модулях тоже. Поэтому ищу среди php

Comment: Найти людей за деньги можно, но ведь так и не узнаю, как самостоятельно менять. А каждый раз дёргать кого-то из-за мелочи не очень хочется.

Comment: ищите в настройках темы, не думаю что в такой теме хардкодили контакты

Answer (score 0):

Изменяй файлы view header.tpl& footer.tpl

Файлы доступны по адресу site.ru\catalog\view\theme\default\template\common\

В место \default\ заходи в свою тему.

PS. А вообще гугли файловая структура OpenCart 2

Comment: Спасибо )) а php трогать не нужно?

Comment: Если у вас информация не будет меняться, то я думаю, можно прописать как статичную... Хотя по хорошему надо добавить поля в БД, изменить модель, затем в контроллере передать переменные в view и уже там выводить)

Comment: Ага, понял. Благодарю

Comment: php лучше начинать трогать после его изучения